# number of subset forming polygon

Tags: combinatorics, polygons

Given a set $S = \{ 1 , 2 , 3,\ldots, n\}$. How can I find number of subsets of size $K$ ($K < n$)  whose elements taken as length of edges can form a convex polygon ($K$-sided).

Comment: Do the numbers represent the lengths of the edges? Surely any finite set of numbers can form the lengths of edges of a convex polygon in the plane?

Comment: yes number represents length of edges @Justpassingby

Comment: ( 1 , 2 , 3 ,6 ) do not form a convex polygon @Justpassingby

Comment: The restriction is that the longest edge must be shorter than the sum of the other edges.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Intuitively that's correct but is that the only restriction?

Comment: While we think about buttressing that intuition, note that the number $f(n)$ of subsets (of cardinality greater than 2) where the largest number is strictly less than the sum of the other numbers should satisfy the recursion $f(n+1)-f(n)=\sum_{2\leq k<n}p(k, n-\left({k \atop 2}\right))$ (the right hand side is the number of ways of selecting at least two numbers among the first $n$ whose sum is exactly $n$, using partitions).

Comment: @cr001 Yes. To form a convex polygon it is necessary that the longest side is longer than the path formed by all other sides. And it is also sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Some recursions (too long for comment):

Let $f(n,k,s)$ denote the number of $k$-sets $\{a_1,\ldots, a_{k}\}\subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $a_1+\ldots +a_{k}\ge s$. Then we have the recursion
$$f(n,k,s)=\begin{cases} f(n-1,k,s)+f(n-1,k-1,s-n)&\text{if $n\ge k\ge0$ and $s>0$}\\n\choose k&\text{if $n\ge k\ge 0$ and $s\le 0$}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$
Let $F(n,k)$  denote the number of $k$-sets $\{a_1,\ldots, a_{k}\}\subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$ that can form a convex polygon.
The polygon condition is equivalent to the largest element being strictly less than the sum of the remaining elements. Hence we find
$$ F(n,k)=\sum_{m=1}^n f(m-1,k-1,m+1)$$

Comment: do you think f( n , k , s ) can be further simplified to some compact form ?

Comment: @hotrod Well, some immediate simplifications are possible, such as $f(n,k,s)={n\choose k}$ already for $s\le \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, but that is no big deal in the end. But Justpassingby has mentioned some great ideas in comments ...

Answer (score 0):

An approach: Let $a_1,...,a_k$ the subset with $a_i<a_j$ if $i<j$. If you can construct a polygon then $a_k<\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_i$.

But this sum is $\leq (a_k-1)+...+(a_k-(k-1))=(k-1)a_k-k(k-1)/2$.

Comment: No, I didn't assume that. I found a bound for ak

Comment: ohh sorry , my bad